# Parse ruleset template DRL with Drools APIs

Tags: java, drools

I'm currently trying to build a POC that parses a ruleset template written in DRL with Drools 6.4 API in order to translate to a simpler JSON homemade format.

I already did it for basic rulesets using `PackageDescr` class. It doesn't work for templates as this class doesn't support templates syntax.

What classes can I use and, more globally, how can I parse a ruleset template DRL to get an object representation of it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% about this, but my guess is that you will not find any API (public or private) to do what you are looking for. And the reason why is because, I think, Drools will expand a template using a third-party templating framework and then use the resulting `String` as regular DRL.

Hope it helps,